# syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input in haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

rails server is following error,

syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input

```
= simple_form_for @recipe, html: { multipart: true } do |f|
  - if @recipe.errors.any?
    #errors
      %p
        = @recipe.errors.count
          Prevented this recipe from saving
      %ul
        - @recipe.errors.full_messages.each do|msg|
          %li= msg
  .panel-body
    = f.input :title, input_html: { class:  'form-control' }
    = f.input :description, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }

  = f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary"
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is caused by the lines

```
= @recipe.errors.count
  Prevented this recipe from saving
```

The second of these lines is being parsed as a block being passed to the method even though it isn’t. Haml is then inserting the `end`, which ultimately causes the extra `end` error you see.

To fix just indent the lines the same:

```
= @recipe.errors.count
Prevented this recipe from saving
```

Or perhaps you could use [interpolation](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#ruby_interpolation_) here:

```
#{@recipe.errors.count} Prevented this recipe from saving
```

Answer (score 1):

The line after `- if @recipe.errors.any?` needs to be indented one step.

```
= simple_form_for @recipe, html: { multipart: true } do |f|
  - if @recipe.errors.any?
    %p
      = @recipe.errors.count
        Prevented this recipe from saving
    %ul
      - @recipe.errors.full_messages.each do|msg|
        %li= msg
  .panel-body
    = f.input :title, input_html: { class:  'form-control' }
    = f.input :description, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }

  = f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary"
```

Comment: If you really need that comment you need to comment it at the same level as the content. But it's pretty redundant.

Comment: i have copied ur code, but again its giving the same error, the main problem is rails server is giving error at line:15, but the code has only 13 lines.

Comment: If you’re referring to `#errors`, that’s not a comment, that’s [valid Haml](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#implicit_div_elements). The error mist be somewhere else.